# Parent > Child Communication] Input() not detecting changes with complex object

Tags: angular

If you pass a complex object with nested objects as an input, angular doesn't always detect changes made to that complex object. How to solve that?

Example with pseudo-code:

```
template: `<child-component [complexObject]="complexObject"></child-component>`
ParentComponent {
  complexObject = {
   nestedObject: {
     username: ''
   }
 }

 changeComplexObject() {
   this.complexObject.nestedObject.username = 'John Doe';
 }
}


ChildComponent {
  private _complexObject: any;

  @Input() 
  public set complexObject(value: any) {
    this._complexObject = value;

    this.doSomethingWithComplexObject();
  }

  doSomethingWithComplexObject() {
    // stops working after 1 or 2 changes
  }
}
```

Also tried with ngOnChanges, but the behaviour is the same. After 1 or 2 changes to the complex object, angular simply stops detecting changes to this object.
It works fine for value types, for example, number or string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is due to change detection of items that are by reference (arrays and objects). They hold the value in memory and since this doesn't change, change detection doesn't kick in.

What I would do is whenever I have to update the object, I do it immutably no matter how many nested arrays and objects there are.

Try this for your parent component:

```
template: `<child-component [complexObject]="complexObject"></child-component>`
ParentComponent {
  complexObject = {
   nestedObject: {
     username: ''
   }
 }

 changeComplexObject() {
   this.complexObject = {
     ...this.complexObject,
     nestedObject: {
       ...nestedObject,
       userName: 'John Doe',
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Hopefully when you change the location of ram of the object and the nested object, change detection should kick in.